# No mouse button up event when hovering on another element

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mouseevent

I have a canvas with a mouse up and down event and there are normaly around 10-15 clickable objects on the screen. 
If I click down on an element or blank space I can catch the event, but when I release the mouse it its only caught if the mouse wasn't on another element (blank space is fine).

Is there any way in Silverlight (for WP7) to make sure I get a mouse up event no matter where on the screen it its triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply [Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse%28VS.95%29.aspx) the mouse when you get the mousDown event.

(And release it after your mouseUp )